# How to add resources in windows service application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

Is there any way to add ttf font in resources in the windows service application?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of resources? Hardware?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx says: "....and do not show any user interface...". Can you elaborate why you need to add a font to your service and what you already tried? I assume if you want to add it you also are planning on using it.

Comment: I know windows service application do not show any user interface, thanks for reminding. Ok, here's what I am trying to do is my service will show time every half an hour with ttf font. so that's why I want to use ttf font.

Comment: What language are you using to implement this?